# How to make weighted query in laravel 5.2?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a search query, I am not using any packages for this.

```
$title = stopWords($title);

$query->where(function($q) use($title) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++) 
    {
        if ( count($title) > 1 && $i == 0 )
            continue;

        if ( count($title) > 1 ) 
        {
            $q->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $title[$i - 1] . ' ' . $title[$i] . '%');
            $q->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $title[$i - 1] .' '.$title[$i]. '%');
        } 
        else {
            $q->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $title[$i] . '%');
            $q->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $title[$i] . '%');
        }
    }
});
```

I want to give more weight to records that matched the title than the description and order the result by it's weight.

Comment: You probably will need to build your own weight system. Algolia supports weighted columns as far as I know. But Laravel doesn't. At least not out the box.

Comment: @Ian .. I don't need to use algolia or make my own system, I just want it for this specific situation. Thanks

Comment: Well then you clearly do need to make your own logic for it?